Vlookup and Multiply in SQL at once?
I apologize- I am still very new to SQL and getting a handle on the basics.
I have a two tables
Exchange rates:



Currency
Q1 Echange Rate
Q2 Echange Rate




USD
1
1


AUD
.56
.57


EUR
1.12
1.124



Invoices:(in Local Cuurency)
Currency| Jan Invoice| Feb Invoice| March Invoice| April Invoice|

AUD     |   5,000    |     8,000  |       10,000 |      20,000  |
I would like to be able to make a column Jan USD, Feb USD, March USD, April USD (and so on) by taking the exchange rate associated with the currency and quarter and multiplying it by the invoice number.
In excel I could do a simple (Vlookup on the table Invoices, column currency, look in exchange rate to find the match.)(Jan Invoice) and have it fill in a column called "Jan USD"
how would I do this in SQL?
Thank you!
I am honestly so new at SQL that ive messed around a bunch but couldnt figure out how to do both at once

Join tables on currency column and calculate additional columns:
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    exchange_rates (CURRENCY, Q1_RATE, Q2_RATE) AS
        ( Select 'USD', 1, 1        From Dual Union All
          Select 'AUD', 0.56, 0.57  From Dual Union All 
          Select 'EUR', 1.12, 1.124 From Dual 
        ),
    invoices (CURRENCY, JAN_INVOICE, FEB_INVOICE, MAR_INVOICE, APR_INVOICE) AS  
        ( Select 'AUD', 5000, 8000, 10000, 20000 FRom Dual )

--   S Q L :
Select       i.CURRENCY, 
           i.JAN_INVOICE, i.JAN_INVOICE * er.Q1_RATE as JAN_INVOICE_USD,
           i.FEB_INVOICE, i.FEB_INVOICE * er.Q1_RATE as FEB_INVOICE_USD,
           i.MAR_INVOICE, i.MAR_INVOICE * er.Q1_RATE as MAR_INVOICE_USD,
           i.APR_INVOICE, i.APR_INVOICE * er.Q2_RATE as APR_INVOICE_USD
From         invoices i
Inner Join  exchange_rates er ON(er.CURRENCY = i.CURRENCY)

/*      R e s u l t :
CURRENCY JAN_INVOICE JAN_INVOICE_USD FEB_INVOICE FEB_INVOICE_USD MAR_INVOICE MAR_INVOICE_USD APR_INVOICE APR_INVOICE_USD
-------- ----------- --------------- ----------- --------------- ----------- --------------- ----------- ---------------
AUD             5000            2800        8000            4480       10000            5600       20000           11400   */

